# Docker Hubにimageをpushするとエラーになる

Tags: docker

## 問題個所

imageをpushするとアクセス拒否される。

```
# docker images
REPOSITORY                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
dockercon/test             latest              896f1a3a36b2        44 hours ago        529 MB
centos                     latest              470671670cac        3 months ago        237 MB

# image push
docker push dockercon/test:latest
```

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/dockercon/test]
c555f2a4fa06: Preparing 
2bfd1607c09c: Preparing 
cb764bb74596: Preparing 
2d03d772d036: Preparing 
b279b0382422: Preparing 
55b116366b5f: Waiting 
5bad68351841: Waiting 
21335377d997: Waiting 
1a7b04ce32bf: Waiting 
88a4c5f6ce87: Waiting 
8af55873dfab: Waiting 
0683de282177: Waiting 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

## 期待する動作

1. Docker Hubにイメージが配置完了となること
2. 原因を知りたい(必須ではない)
3. なにが原因かデバッグする方法を知りたい

## やったこと

- selinuxは無効化している
- Docker Hubのアカウントは持っている
- 公開は設定はpublicにしている
- docker push前にはdocker loginを実施している
- docker login --username * --passwordも実施している
- docker login docker.ioも実施している
- ~/.docker/config.jsonを削除してdocker loginも実施している
- 別リポジトリを作ってpushしてみたが、アクセス拒否されている
- リポジトリの共同編集者に自身のアカウントを登録した

## 環境

- windows 10
- docker for windows
- wsl(Windows Subsystem for Linux)

```
[root@DESKTOP-DF03I65 ~]# docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26
 Package version: 
 Go version:      go1.10.3
 Git commit:      64e9980/1.13.1
 Built:           Tue Apr 28 14:43:01 2020
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         19.03.8
 API version:     1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
 Package version: 
 Go version:      go1.12.17
 Git commit:      afacb8b
 Built:           Wed Mar 11 01:29:16 2020
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
 Experimental:    false
```

Answer (score 1):

原因は、namespaceがユーザー名になっているからだと考えられます。`dockercon`はあなたのユーザー名でしょうか？https://hub.docker.com/u/dockerconへアクセスする限り、他者の所有物であるような気がします。

docker hubのnamespaceの確認方法は、`docker login`をしたときのユーザー名です。

```sh
$ docker login

Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: [usernname] # ここがあなたのnamespaceになる
Password:
Login Succeeded
```

例えば、https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-worldを自分のnamespaceにpushするときは次のようになります。

```sh
$ docker pull hello-world
$ docker tag hello-world [username]/hello-world
$ docker push [username]/hello-world
```

よって、一度ユーザー名を確認してみてください。[docker pushのドキュメント](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/)も合わせて確認してみてください。